# gin framework version with dep module on golang return gin version 0.0.0

Tags: go, dep

I have a golang with dep module project with version like this

```
dep:
 version     : v0.5.4
 build date  : 2019-07-01
 git hash    : 1f7c19e
 go version  : go1.12.6
 go compiler : gc
 platform    : linux/amd64
 features    : ImportDuringSolve=false
```

I tried to install `gin framework` and when I try to get version of gin, the response like this

```
$gin --version
>gin version 0.0.0
```

I tried to update `gin` but still the same, what should I do?

Comment: "with dep module with version" dep is deprecated since several years. Go 1.12 is unmaintained since several years. Migrate to Go 1.17 and Modules _now_ .

Answer (score 1):

> what should i do?

Update to Go 1.17

Make this a project Module aware.

Update dependencies.